# Uso de LinQ con arreglos multidimensionales

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, matrices, lambda

Necesito manipular la informacion de un arreglo multidimensional, para realizar una sumatoria de la columna cantidad, utilizando LinQ o lambda, adjunto imagen del arreglo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo de ejemplo es:

```
 public class sumatoria
    {
        public string cant { get; set; }
        public string descrp { get; set; }

        public sumatoria(string cantidad, string descripcion)
        {
            cant = cantidad;
            descrp = descripcion;
        }
    }

        string[,] arreglo = new string[3, 2];

        arreglo[0, 0] = "10";
        arreglo[0, 1] = "descripcion 1";
        arreglo[1, 0] = "15";
        arreglo[1, 1] = "descripcion 2";
        arreglo[2, 0] = "7";
        arreglo[2, 1] = "descripcion 3";

        List<sumatoria> lista = new List<sumatoria>()
        {
            //Necesito hacerlo con un bucle ya que el arreglo varia de tamaño segun la informacion del usuario
            //i -> contador
            new sumatoria() {cant = arreglo[i, 0], descrp = arreglo[i, 1]},
        };

        int sumaCantidad = lista.Sum(x1 => x1.cant);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La cantidad la estás guardando como **string** y debe ser de tipo **int**. Pon este código:

```
List<sumatoria> lista = new List<sumatoria>();

for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
{
   lista.Add(new sumatoria(Convert.ToInt32(arr[i, 0]), arr[i, 1]));
}
```

Declaras una **lista de tipo sumatoria** y mediante un **ciclo for** recorres tu arreglo y añades a la lista un nuevo elemento de tipo sumatoria que su **propiedad cant** va a ser igual a lo que se guarda en **arr[i, 0]** pero convertido a **int**, ya que en el arreglo se guarda como **string**, y la **propiedad descripcion** se obtiene de **arr[i, 1]**.

Posteriormente vendría obtener la suma usando **Linq**:

```
var suma = lista.Sum(l => l.cant);
```

De esta forma obtengo la suma de toda las cantidades de la lista.

En tu ejemplo haces uso de la **cláusula using** para construir tu lista, pero debes tener en cuenta que cuando se salga de este bloque la variable que guarda tu lista se destruye igual que todo lo que se declara dentro de tu **bloque using**, por tanto en tu ejemplo no puedes hacer la suma de la lista, ya que la estás haciendo fuera del **bloque using** y ya lista no existe fuera del **bloque using**.

Para hacer uso de **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Tu ejemplo esta incompleto, no explicas como calculas el numero de filas.

Comment: @CristinaCarrasco, fila es una variable hipotética que representa cualquier valor,  asumi que se iba a entender lo que trataba de decir

Comment: Bueno te pongo ese comentario porque en los arreglos multidimensionales no es tan simple obtener el numero de rows y columnas, hay que utilizar el método GetLenght el cual recibe el numero de dimensión.

Comment: @CristinaCarrasco, ok bonita, de todos modos tu respuesta dice como obtenerlo, no creo que el usuario tenga problemas, gracias

Comment: @CristinaCarrasco, gracias por la atencion, no se preocupen por el numero de filas, se como resolver.

Comment: @Japv, tu forma la habia intentado un tiempo atras, pero me muestra el error siguiente:            

Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Estado suprimido
Error CS7036 No se ha dado ningún argumento que corresponda al parámetro formal requerido 'cantidad' de 'Program.sumatoria.sumatoria(int, string)' 
 El visualStudio lo marca en "new sumatoria()"

Comment: @Ariel, ese error me parece que es pq tu constructor de sumatoria tiene dos parámetros y tu estas construyendo el objeto sin pasarle parametros

Comment: @Ariel debería ser new sumatoria(cantidad, descripcion)

Comment: @Ariel, edite la respuesta y lo puse como es,  el objeto de debe construirse pasándole los dos parámetros al constructor, ya que tu constructor recibe dos parámetros, fíjate para que veas

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120355/discussion-between-japv-and-ariel).

Comment: @Japv, ok, reviso.

Answer (score 3):

Basándome en tu código se me ocurren dos soluciones:

```
private static int ObtenerSumaLinq(string[,] arreglo)
{
    //Obteniendo TODOS los datos del arreglo y convirtiendolo a int si es posible la conversion si no dejar en cero
    var suma = (from string item in arreglo select item)
                    .Sum(x => int.TryParse(x, out int y) ? int.Parse(x) : 0);

    //NOTA: Esta solucion tiene un problema, si la descripcion es un numero tambien sera sumada

    return suma;
}

private static int ObtenerSumaCiclo(string[,] arreglo)
{
    //Utilziando ciclo:
    int suma = 0;

    //Si el arreglo solo tiene dos dimensiones, la dimension 0 serian las filas
    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        //Dimension 1 serian las columnas
        for (int j = 0; j < arreglo.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            int.TryParse(arreglo[i, j], out int valor);
            suma += valor;
        }
    }
    return suma;
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[,] arreglo = new string[3, 2];

    arreglo[0, 0] = "10";
    arreglo[0, 1] = "descripcion 1";
    arreglo[1, 0] = "15";
    arreglo[1, 1] = "descripcion 2";
    arreglo[2, 0] = "7";
    arreglo[2, 1] = "descripcion 3";

    Console.WriteLine($"Suma utilizando linq \n\t{ObtenerSumaLinq(arreglo)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Suma utilizando ciclo \n\t{ObtenerSumaCiclo(arreglo)}");

    string[,] arreglo2 = new string[3, 4];

    arreglo2[0, 0] = "10";
    arreglo2[0, 1] = "descripcion 1";
    arreglo2[0, 2] = "2";
    arreglo2[0, 3] = "descripcion 1-2";
    arreglo2[1, 0] = "15";
    arreglo2[1, 1] = "descripcion 2";
    arreglo2[1, 2] = "150";
    arreglo2[1, 3] = "descripcion 2";
    arreglo2[2, 0] = "7";
    arreglo2[2, 1] = "descripcion 3";
    arreglo2[2, 2] = "7";
    arreglo2[2, 3] = "descripcion 3";

    Console.WriteLine($"Suma utilizando linq \n\t{ObtenerSumaLinq(arreglo2)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Suma utilizando ciclo \n\t{ObtenerSumaCiclo(arreglo2)}");

    /*
    List<sumatoria> lista = new List<sumatoria>()
    {
        //Necesito hacerlo con un bucle ya que el arreglo varia de tamaño segun la informacion del usuario
        //i -> contador
        new sumatoria() {cant = arreglo[i, 0], descrp = arreglo[i, 1]},
    };

    int sumaCantidad = lista.Sum(x1 => x1.cant);
    */
}
```